# How do I solve for $X$ when $X=AXA^T+B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve for $X$ in
$$X=AXA^T+B$$
where $X$, $A$, and $B$ are all real square matrices. $B$ is positive (semi) definite. There is an analytic solution when $B=I$ by using the Woodbury matrix identity, but I am not sure about a more general case. Is there a way to solve this analytically? If not, what would be a good analytic approximation or a numerical method to solve for $X$?

Comment: This is a [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation).

Comment: Very interesting! I thought this is an equation specific to what I am dealing with. It is nice how there is a condition to satisfy the equality. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ X = AXA^⊤ + B ⟺ (_{n⊗n}-A⊗A)⋅X = B$$

If $\,±1\not∈ \operatorname{spec}(A): X = (_{n⊗n}-A⊗A)^{-1}⋅B$

If $ρ(A)<1:\quad X = \big(\sum_{k=0}^{∞}(A⊗A)^k\big) ⋅B  = \sum_{k=0}^{∞}A^kB(A^⊤)^k$

**Note:** $(A⊗B)_{ik, jl} ≔ A_{ij}B_{kl}$ and $⋅X ≔ \big(∑_{jl}_{ik, jl} X_{jl}\big)_{ik}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am confused why there are two cases/ifs. Is it not a necessary condition for A to have a spectral radius smaller than one? Wikipedia page says A needs to be stable. If it is necessary why is there another condition for a separate case (the first condition in your answer)? I think I don’t understand what ‘spec(A) does not include {1,-1}’ means… Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @CWC The Wikipedia page talks about a unique solution $X>0$, you didn't specify that $X$ needed to be positive definite. $\operatorname{spec}(A)$ is the spectrum of $A$, i.e. the set of all eigenvalues. Since $\operatorname{spec}(A⊗B) = \operatorname{spec}(A)⋅\operatorname{spec}(B) = \{λ⋅μ∣λ∈\operatorname{spec}(A)∧μ∈\operatorname{spec}(B) \}$, it follows that $_{n⊗n} - A⊗A$ is invertible if and only if $1\not∈\operatorname{spec}(A⊗A) = \operatorname{spec}(A)^2$, i.e. if and only if $±1\not∈\operatorname{spec}(A)$.

Comment: @CWC The second case is simply the series expansion of  $(1-q)^{-1}$, i.e. the geometric series.

Comment: @CWC See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product, the properties hold 1:1 for the tensor-product, since the Kronecker Product is more or less just a flattened representation of the tensor product. But I prefer to have 4 indices instead of having to do index arithmetic.